# Empirical error in Kullback-Leibler KL divergence estimation

Tags: distributions, entropy, kullback-leibler

In computing the Kullback-Leibler KL divergence $D(P\|Q)$ from an empirical data, it may happen that $Q(x)=0<P(x)$ at some sample point $x$ (due to data error -- I put it in parenthesis now, after the helpful discussion below) and $D(P\|Q)=\infty$. What are some good treatments of this singularity from estimation error?

Comment: If you can identify the data error as a  real data error, not just a "the data didn't fit my model" error, then you should remove it from the sample.

Comment: @jbowman: Maybe. But that entails I remove the data point from $P$ as well. What do you think of my answer below?

Comment: If it's truly a data error, then it should be removed from both $P$ and $Q$...  Consider a $Q = $ Binomial($n = 3$) vs a $P = $ Poisson ($\lambda = 1$) comparison, with one observation encoded as $4$.  Either this is a data error or the Binomial distribution is not a possible model, and $D = \infty$ isn't unreasonable in that case.  It's about informing *you*, the user, that $Q$ simply doesn't work as a model.

Comment: @jbowman: I agree. I did not make my question clear. The image of the random variable is in the continuum. The discretization of the continuum axis makes some of the interval empty. I guess I need to find other more robust method of estimating the probability distribution. I will edit my question later.

Comment: It's ok if the interval is empty, the sum over $x$ just won't include any points in that interval.

Comment: @jbowman: The interval can be empty for the sample of $Q$ but not for that of $P$. $D=\infty$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135645/discussion-between-hans-and-jbowman).

Comment: @jbowman: I responded to you in the chat room. Please re-enter.

Comment: as you said @Hans, isn't the issue that you need a better probability estimate eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation

Comment: @seanv507: Yes, that was one solution I thought of before. But I forgot why I said "empirical data". Maybe it was because I wanted the data raw rather than processed...

Anyway, what do you think of my proposal as one answer below?

Comment: I can't tell you if it's a good solution for your problem, as you haven't described the problem for which you are using KL divergence.   eg it depends on *your* application if symmetry is meaningful or not .  As @jbowman said, $D=\infty$ may well be a sensible output (for some sample points).

Comment: @seanv507: I agree.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution. Use [Jensen-Shannon divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%E2%80%93Shannon_divergence) in place of Kullback-Leibler divergence. It resides in the interval $[0,1]$ in base $2$ logarithm.